# Apply If/Then on a Range (google-apps-script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm slowly working my way towards understanding how to formulate a common programming process, but I'm in need of someone who is willing to further teach me how to fish (in this JS pond).

I want to test a range of cells (ex: A1:A10) and if there is a "," found within a cell in that range, I want to write a formula in the cell 5 columns to the right of that cell.

So far I have been able to get it to work when specifying specific cells, but I'm not sure how to adopt this to handle a range of cells.

(btw, this is something that I understand how to do in VBA - the absence of the SPLIT function notwithstanding - but this language is obviously a very different animal)

Here is what I have now:

```
var defSheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")   
var test1 = defSheet1.getRange("A1").getValue();
var splitCell = '=SPLIT(A1,",")';
if (test1.indexOf(",") !== -1)  
{
defSheet1.getRange("F1").setFormula(splitCell);
}
 else 
  { 
Browser.msgBox("NO SPLIT NECESSARY");   
  }
```

(btw, the actual range is going to be determined by using getDataRange, but for simplicity sake, I'm using a pre-established range here)

I've already learned quite a bit here, and I'm gradually gaining the ability to "think" in JS, but a VBA "*For x = 1 to numLastRow*" concept isn't clicking for me in JS.

Comment: You could use the following spreadsheet formula put into cell F1: `=arrayformula(iferror(split(A:A, ",")))`

Comment: @David Tew - Very interesting alternative. It would not have occurred to me to take it in that direction. That concept is a keeper. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're working on multiple rows and/or columns from spreadsheets, one challenge is converting between indexes and the various ways that cell locations can be expressed.

- In A1Notation, columns are expressed first, as a letter, followed by row, as a number starting at 1.
- R1C1 notation flips the order of rows and columns, and both dimensions are numbers starting from 1.
- Arrays in javascript start from index 0. As you evolve your script to use `getDataRange().getValues()`, this will be important. In the two-dimensional array returned by `getValues()`, rows are expressed first, then column, as in `data[row][column]`. The upper bound of your loops will need to be adjusted accordingly, and you may need to `+1` if you're referencing Range methods like `setFormula()`.

The code snippet below will do what you're looking for, as a starting point. I've left out the `else` block to reduce noise. Note the use of `getA1Notation()` to build the `SPLIT` formula dynamically - a straight-forward evolution of your script.

You'll need to define `numLastRow` yourself, and since the script is accessing Range methods throughout, `10` would mean cell `A10`.

```
var defSheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")

for (var x=1; x<=numLastRow; x++) {
  var srcRange = defSheet1.getRange(x,1);
  var value = srcRange.getValue();  // Get value at Row x, Column 1
  if (value.indexOf(",") !== -1) {
    var splitCell = '=SPLIT(' + srcRange.getA1Notation() + ',",")';
    defSheet1.getRange(x,5).setFormula(splitCell);
  }
};
```

Comment: Hmmm.... that is definitely something that I can sink my teeth into! However if you had not provided your very appreciated explanation, I'm pretty sure that my eyes would have glazed over for a while. Many thanks for the lesson (especially) and the code (of course). I will now play around with this and see how many ways I can modify it to do the things that I need it to do. THANK YOU very much!

Comment: Btw, on line 6 there is a missing comma after the last of the open single-quotes (prior to the last of the double-quotes). That line should read: var splitCell = '=SPLIT(' + srcRange.getA1Notation() + ',",")'; I only point that out for anyone else who might come here and snag that code for their own use.

Comment: Just curious, why is x "<=" instead of "==" or "===" ?

Comment: Wow, that CodeAcademy looks promising. Now all I need to find is a link to a website where I can get "free extra time in the day"! :P Thanks for all of your help Mosgdad. I still haven't earned enough "rep" here to adequately give proper thanks in this particular realm, but you can be sure that my appreciation for your time and assistance has reached well beyond the confines of SO. Many thanks!